# Pass checked checkbox data attribute through JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkboxes in a for each loop all with different data attributes.

```
  <input data-pid="<?php echo $name ?>" class="live" name="live" id="live" type="checkbox" value="">
```

In JQuery I am trying to fetch the data attribute of the checked option and whether it is checked or not.

```
   $(".live").click(function() {

    var n = this.id
    var a = this.attr("data-pid");
```

I don't seem to be able to get the id or attr

Comment: in your function you can do `this.checked` to see if it is checked or not

Comment: how about the data attribute

Comment: change `var a = this.attr("data-pid");` to `var a = $(this).attr("data-pid");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/nydo9ues/1/

```
$('.live').change(function(){
var chkbx=$(this);
console.log(chkbx.data());//Will give you a JSON Object with your data https://api.jquery.com/data/
console.log(chkbx.attr('id'));//id of the element changing
console.log(chkbx.is(':checked'));//Status of the checkbox


});
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` is a jQuery method so you have to use `$(this).attr()` not `this.attr()`

```js
$(function() {
   $(".live").change(function() {
     var n = this.id
     var a = $(this).attr("data-pid");
     console.log('id=', n, ' pid=', a , ' checked=', this.checked)
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-pid="1" id="live_1" class="live">
<input type="checkbox" data-pid="2" id="live_2" class="live">
<input type="checkbox" data-pid="3" id="live_3" class="live">
<input type="checkbox" data-pid="4" id="live_4" class="live">
<input type="checkbox" data-pid="5" id="live_5" class="live">
```

Use your console to check for errors. You should have seen one for `this.attr()` is not a function